# Deleted some files being versioned by Mercurial, how do I commit those deletes?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, commit, delete-file, revert

I deleted a few files on my local filesystem which I am not using anymore and are just junk.  Unfortunately they are tracked by version control (Mercurial).  Now I see a large red '!' saying it is out of sync because of the missing files.  How can I tell Mercurial that it's OK to remove those files without reverting all of them and selecting delete on them individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either tell it to forget those files:

```
hg forget XYZ
hg commit ...
```

Or use the addremove command, or addremove option for commit:

```
hg addremove
Hg commit ...
```

Or

```
hg commit --addremove ...
```

Use the help to find more info on these commands:

```
hg help forget
hg help commit
```

Comment: Note that addremove might pick up other changes you might not want to commit. My advice is to be explicit, use the forget command.